# Объясните про структуру приложения вкратце пожалуйста

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, swift3

Такой вопрос, пробую писать под ios сам)
Интересует такой вопрос - я все функции (какие либо действия/вычисления) описываю в "viewDidLoad()" правильно ли это ?
А обращение с одного ViewController на другой осуществляю через "prepare Segue"
Может можно создать отдельный файл по типу как в C++ и подключить его к проекту где будут происходить все вычисления..
И еще такой вопрос: сейчас начнется курс 2017 от Стэнфорда по ios разработке) хочу его изучить.. если кто-то смотрел/проходил то кто что может сказать ?) все вроде как довольные и хвалят

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> все функции (какие либо действия/вычисления) описываю в
>   "viewDidLoad()" правильно ли это ?

Нет. Если хоть немного сложные вычисления, нужно выносить в отдельный поток. Некоторые действия нельзя вызывать в `viewDidLoad`, поэтому нужно запускать, к примеру, в `viewDidAppear`.

> обращение с одного ViewController на другой осуществляю через "prepare
>   Segue"

Разные варианты могут быть. Можно, к примеру, создавать программно, присваивать значения и запускать `presentViewController`.

> курс 2017 от Стэнфорда по ios разработке

Интересный и с юмором.

Comment: Понял спасибо :) почитаю о том что вы написали хорошего дня :)